# peer dependency issue in npm install

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-install, npm-scripts, peer-dependencies

I am working on a personal site which uses create-react-app and noticed that after installing MUI, every time i npm install, i get peer dependency errors. I think it might have to do with different library versions i have, but im not really sure what the issue is. I think seeing my package might help someone else understand where the problem lies.

Screenshots of my errors in terminal and my package are here! Please help! :)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1M0I.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlHV5.png)

i've tried uninstalling mui (which it wont let me do because of other peer dependencies?), changing versions of react, deleting node modules and package lock files, but i keep getting the same 'unable to resolve dependency tree'
9:16

--force seems to work temporarily but it seems like its not the actual solution because i still cant install libraries 'naturally'

Comment: Perhaps show the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes what I use when dealing with peer dependency problems.

1. install the version of the peer dependency I need locally to the package.json.
2. install this npm package: npm-force-resolutions

```js
devDependencies: {
  "npm-force-resolutions": "0.0.3" //I'm sure there is a more modern update by now!
}
```

3. Provide an additional item - "resolutions" - in the package.json pointing to that peer dependency.

**package.json**

```js
{
  "resolutions": {
    "minimist": "1.2.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "minimist": "1.2.5",
  }
}
```

And then add a script which runs after every time you install something new .

```js
  "scripts": {
    "preinstallAfter": "node ./node_modules/npm-force-resolutions/index.js",
   }
```

Then re-install
(Note: npm ci is better because it does not try to install minor variations of package files. It takes only what is explicitly declared in your package-lock.json file. That way its consistent if sharing on a repo between different operating systems. )

- npm ci

Hope it helps